# update account field after merge is complete

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to update an account after the merge, I have this error :

> Object "001233fgde56ee"  is currently in a merge operation, therefore a
>   trigger can not update it.

so for example :

```
Merge acc1 acc2;
acc1.field = 'update field';
update acc1;
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: yes,
the merge statement is :
before delete account, after delete account ,before update account, after update account .

so i did it in after update trigger .

and i retiver the Account deleted  :
   List<Account> oldAccounts = [select id,name,MasterRecordId,Number_of_Call_Reports__c  from Account where isDeleted=true and MasterRecordId in :newAcctIDs ALL ROWS];

then i update account merged

Comment: You are making it very difficult to determine where you are stuck. Please [edit] your question with any additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `update` to a `@future` method:

```
@future
public static void updateAccountField(Id accountId)
{
    update new Account(Id=accountId, field='update field');
}
```

Your code snippet would then change to:

```
merge acc1 acc2;
updateAccountField(acc1.Id);
```

Comment: thanks for response,
i try it, but the method is not called, i don't know why :

              updateAccountMerge(masterList [0].Id);

    }
    
     @future
    public static void updateAccountMerge(Id accountId)
    { 
   
      AccountRollup  accObj = new AccountRollup ();
      update new Account(Id=accountId, field = 'ttt');
    }

Comment: @momo Not sure how you are trying to call this method...please check my update and edit your post to clarify if it didn't help.